# How to download jar file from github source code?

Tags: java, eclipse, github, jar

I need to use a `nxParser` library to parse my `NTriple` files in eclipse.

Apparently, the only source that perfectly works is [this github code](https://github.com/nxparser/nxparser) but this is just the source code and I need a built-in jar library.

Could anyone help me how can I use a source code as a built-in jar file?

Answer (score 7):

If you need a jar file itself rather than adding pom.xml click on below link to download jar file http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/semanticweb/yars/nxparser-parsers/2.3.3/nxparser-parsers-2.3.3.jar

If you want to create jar file from github follow the below steps,

**In Linux/Mac**

1.Clone the repository

```
git clone https://github.com/nxparser/nxparser.git
cd nxparser
```

2.Build the project

```
./gradlew build
```

3.Find jar file

```
`nxparser-parsers/build/libs/nxparser-parsers-2.3.4-SNAPSHOT.jar`
```

Comment: Not sure why your answer was just dowvoted: like mine, it is a correct one

Comment: Yes, I am not sure about it.

Comment: And kind of strange too that the person who upvoted my (less helpful one) forget to upvote the other two. Fixed that :-)... Merry Xmas everyone.

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned in the README](https://github.com/nxparser/nxparser#binaries)

> Compiles are available on Maven Central. The [groupId is org.semanticweb.yars and the artifactId nxparser](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.semanticweb.yars/nxparser-parsers).

See for instance [NxParser Parsers » 2.3.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.semanticweb.yars/nxparser-parsers/2.3.3)

With maven for instance, you would add to your `pom.xml` dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.semanticweb.yars/nxparser-parsers -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.semanticweb.yars</groupId>
    <artifactId>nxparser-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @VonC! What if I dont implement a maven and just want to go for a simple java project?

Comment: @Reihan_amn the same page has a download link: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/semanticweb/yars/nxparser-parsers/2.3.3/nxparser-parsers-2.3.3.jar. But that is not the best practice: you need a declarative approach where you declare your dependencies, in order to get a reproducible build. That declaration is done in a pom.xml, or in a gradle file, or in any other system you want, but it ensures that another developer will be able to build your project with the same dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You see, this is open source. It comes with **build** files and is also available via maven.

So "worst" case you get a full git clone and **build** that JAR on your own; to then import it into your eclipse project.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by it comes with build files?
I do not want to use the maven actually.

Comment: There is a gradle build file in there... Just see that other answer to your question! And for the record: you probably don't have to use maven all the time. Just use it to pull that jar to your local disk. Then copy the file to your eclipse setup.